Seeders to populate database

import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { Seeder } from 'typeorm-extension';
import { User } from '../../user/entities/user.entity';

export class UserSeeder implements Seeder {
async run(dataSource: DataSource): Promise<void> {
    const userRepository = dataSource.getRepository(User);

    const userData = [
      {
        name: 'sharun',
        email: 'raj@gmail.com',
        password: '12345',
      },
      {
        name: 'raj',
        email: 'raj@gmail.com',
        password: 'raj',
      },
      {
        name: 'raj2',
        email: 'raj@gmail.com',
        password: 'raj',
      },
      {
        name: 'raj3',
        email: 'raj@gmail.com',
        password: 'raj',
      },
      {
        name: 'raj4',
        email: 'raj@gmail.com',
        password: 'raj',
      },
    ];
    
    const existingUsers = await userRepository.find({ where: userData.map(user => ({ name: user.name })) });
    const newUsers = userData.filter(user => !existingUsers.some(existingUser => existingUser.name === user.name));
    
    if (newUsers.length > 0) {
      await userRepository.insert(newUsers);
      newUsers.forEach(newUser => {
        console.log(`User '${newUser.name}' added to the database.`);
      });
    }
    
    console.log("User Seeding Completed\n");

}
}


import { DataSource } from 'typeorm'
import { runSeeder, Seeder,  } from 'typeorm-extension'
import { UserSeeder } from './user.seed'

export class MainSeeder implements Seeder {
async run(
dataSource: DataSource,

    ): Promise<void> {
        await runSeeder(dataSource, UserSeeder)
        
    }

}

created a user seeder to insert data and created a main seeder and called it and run this my question is this same i can do with the loops then why to seeders and populate the data can anyone help me with this to why to use seeders not loops because its just a function which is run when we call from the cli
